# Which analysis to use for correlating EEG data to symptomatology?

Tags: spss

I have collected data on ADHD symptoms via questionnaires, so the participants score anywhere from 0-23 on this questionnaire and that would determine severity. Higher score = higher symptomatology. I also have EEG data, and I am looking at specific frequency bands (mainly theta and beta waves), this is in the form of a power spectrum. So, I believe I have two continuous variables(?).

I want to see if the severity of symptomatology is reflected in the EEG data, so if more severe symptoms (higher score) show higher theta power and lower beta power in the frontal regions. Which analysis would be useful? I have not grouped the participants (e.g., scores 1-10, 10-17, 17-23) as I do not have access to the data yet.

If possible, I want to control for sex and age as well.

I will be using SPSS and as you may have seen I know little about statistics. Thank you very much for taking the time to read this and hopefully helping a very stressed student out.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are probably working with a mentor at University? The best step is always to talk to them about what confuses you. In your case, you will want to run a linear regression between symptoms and EEG, with age and sex as covariates. Probably symptoms as your dependent, and eeg, age, and sex as independents. There are many [tutorials](https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/linear-regression-using-spss-statistics.php) online.